# If I receive files over the FTP command line, where will they be saved?

Tags: command-line, ftp

If I receive files over the FTP command line, where will they be saved?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As Shevek noted, the files will go to the current directory when ftp was launched

*-or-*

the last specified directory from an `lcd` (local change dir) command within the ftp session.

Answer (score 2):

In whichever folder the command prompt was in when you launched the FTP command

Answer (score 0):

Local Disk (C:)-> Users->{your current user}-> *here you can find the file you get FTP*